# Adding filtering to an existing query

Tags: c#, linq

I need to simplify this code as well as a Linq query:

```
 var data = from linq_row in trend_data.AsEnumerable()
                       group linq_row by linq_row["questionnaire_uniquename"] into g

                       select new
                       {
                           questionnaire_uniquename = g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString(),
                           question_name = g.First<DataRow>()["question_name"].ToString(),
                           question_score_type = g.First<DataRow>()["question_score_type"].ToString(),
                           sparkline_data = g.Select(s => s["trend_score"].ToString()).ToArray()
                       }; ;
            int rowspan = 2;
```

Based on some condition, I am adding just adding filtering to an existing query and modifying the selected query here. Instead of selecting `question_name`, I want to select `response_label` from a data table.

```
if (criteria.CorporateSummaryExpand == "1")
{
    data =
       from linq_row in trend_data.AsEnumerable()
       group linq_row by linq_row["questionnaire_uniquename"] into g
       where g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP5000]"
       && g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP5008]"
       && g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP1130]"

       select new
       {
           questionnaire_uniquename = g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString(),
           question_name = g.First<DataRow>()["response_label"].ToString(),
           question_score_type = g.First<DataRow>()["question_score_type"].ToString(),
           sparkline_data = g.Select(s => s["trend_score"].ToString()).ToArray()
       };
    rowspan = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have provided you can combine  the two queries into one. You should also consider removing constants like `"1"`, `2`, `4` with meaningful names.

```
var yourCondition = criteria.CorporateSummaryExpand == "1";
var data = from linq_row in trend_data.AsEnumerable()
           group linq_row by linq_row["questionnaire_uniquename"] into g
           where (criteria.CorporateSummaryExpand != "1") || (yourCondition  && g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP5000]"
                   && g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP5008]"
                   && g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString() != "[Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Question].&[OFSP]&[OFSP1130]")
           select new
           {
                questionnaire_uniquename = g.First<DataRow>()["questionnaire_uniquename"].ToString(),
                question_name =yourCondition  ? g.First<DataRow>()["response_label"].ToString() : g.First<DataRow>()["question_name"].ToString(),
                question_score_type = g.First<DataRow>()["question_score_type"].ToString(),
                sparkline_data = g.Select(s => s["trend_score"].ToString()).ToArray()
           }; 
int rowspan = yourCondition ? 4 : 2;
```

Comment: thanks. but actually select statement also differed in condition. please check above question code

Comment: In condition part ,question_name = g.First<DataRow>()["response_label"].ToString(),

Comment: @SivaRajini I've fixed the code

Comment: but repeating the condition again and again is that fine?

Comment: because of that reason only i had placed in single if part

Comment: You can extract it into a variable, though compiler would have surely optimized it